# How can I search in document library from the root folder with fields that exist in the files to get the target files using pnp modern search

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

For example, if I am in the root folder in a document library and want to search for the files with fields that don't exist in the root folder,

is there a way to do that with PNP modern search?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query in Query template, it can search from the root folder in document library, then you can use the fields to search for files.

```
{searchTerms} path: https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/zellatest/LibraryName/FolderName
```

I have answered the steps in the [Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/905399/how-can-i-search-in-document-library-from-the-root.html?childToView=905995#answer-905995).